# How can I add plugin to heroku repo?

Tags: heroku, github

I gave `heroku plugins:install heroku-first-blog` on terminal.I got an error something like this

```
 Installing plugin heroku-first-blog... !
         ▸    Plugin not found
         !    error installing plugin heroku-first-blog
```

Answer (score 1):

To use [heroku plugins](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-cli-plugins) you need to specify the plugins git repository URL. For instance, if you wanted to install the [heroku accounts](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts) plugin you might say:

```
heroku plugins:install https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git
```

Here's what happens when I run this command locally myself:

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git                                                   
Installing https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git... done
```

Comment: When I am trying to install plugins,it will stop unexpectedly.

Comment: Can you update your post and include a lot of what is happening when you run the command I pasted?

Comment: when I run the command you pasted,it tried to installing the plugins and stop the installation unexpectedly after a few moments.

Comment: Does it finish downloading the plugin? It sounds like it is failing because of internet connectivity issues?

Comment: No.it is not downloaded.And also there is no internet connectivity issues.I tried this in another system with  another internet connection..It shows the same problem.

Comment: And also how can I connect an existing git repository to my heroku app?

Comment: I just updated my answer to show you the exact copy+pasted output of what happens when I run the above command myself. It works fine on my two computers here at home. The only thing I can think of that would break this are: you have internet connectivity issues, or you don't have Git installed?

Comment: For connecting to a git repository, you will want to post a new question since that is a different topic on SO.

Comment: my heroku version is heroku-cli/5.6.26-e6aeac4 (darwin-amd64) go1.7.5. Actually the http installation method for heroku plugin was not supported anymore. The heroku doc only support plugins with json config right now.